Angular and tree shaking environment.ts file
I have a general question,
If I have my environment file
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  featureAEnabled: false,
};

Then in a component
if (environtment.featureAEnabled) {
// Doing stuff
}

Will this still be a part of the bundle even do it will never be used?

You mean this will work even after creating a build?

Will what be part of the bundle?

I mean, will the code within the if statement be tree shaken or will it be a part of main bundle?
The environment const will never change so there is no real point in having that code in the bundle.. right?

Good question. My understanding is that Angular tree shaking is based on imports, so I would assume that code will not be removed. It shouldn't be too hard to craft an experiment to find out. It is possible to dynamically import Angular modules. I've done it using import() and createNgModule. Note that I'm still on Angular 15 and I think there may be better support for dynamic module loading in newer versions.

environment CAN change later. const only means it cannot be reassigned. But single properties of environment like featureAEnabled CAN change at runtime
